# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' in Python

Tags: python

I am having problems with this bit of code

```
import csv
temp = open("townsfile.csv", "r")
towns = temp.read()
temp.close()
print(towns)

eachTown = towns.split("\n")
print (eachTown)

record = eachTown.split(",")

for line in eachTown:
    record = eachItem.split(",")

print(record)

newlist=[]

newlist.append(record)

newlist=[]
for eachItem in eachTown:
record = eachItem.split(",")
newlist.append(record)

print(newlist)
```

It returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:/Python practice/towns.py", line 10, in <module>
    record = eachTown.split(",")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Because `eachTown` is a list of towns...

Comment: `eachTown` is a list, yes. Why do you have `record = each<something>.split(',')` three times?

Comment: Also, don't re-invent the CSV-reading wheel. Just use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: I just love python, the error message is already pretty clear!

Comment: What will the script be doing? i.e. what does your CSV look like and what output are your trying to get? Please edit the question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module gives you this text parsing functionality, you do not need to do it yourself.

```
import csv
with open("townsfile.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    towns = list(reader)

print(towns)
```

The problem you have is that `list.split()` does not exist, you are trying to use `str.split()` but you already split it into a `list` of `str`s. You would need to do it for every `str` in the list.

Comment: This does not work? Can you please give me the correct correct that you think will work TypeError:  expected at least 1 arguments, got 0

Comment: Sotty I was missing a comma

Answer (score 0):

```
eachTown = towns.split("\n")
```

This code return list. List don't have attribute split. You should replace

```
record = eachTown.split(",")
```

like this

```
records = [rec.split(",") for rec in eachTown]
```

But better if you start using [module csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for read this file.